# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS does not boot after HDMI connection

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, asus

I have an ASUS VivoBook using a NVIDIA geforce graphics. I have had this problem several times, but always managed to fix it by rolling back software updates or using older kernels.

Currently using kernel 5.8.0-53-generic, tried to boot with previous versions since this has happened to me before and solved the issue, but not this time. When I try to boot from older kernels, it gets stuck on 'Initial ram disk'

I can't even boot ubuntu if I properly shut down the computer, I need to force shut it for it to be able to get to the grub menu.

Also tried to clean, update, upgrade. Tried to boot with the secure boot option in my BIOS on and off, no difference.

I see this happening every time I disconnect an external HDMI connected device, such as external screens or projectors.

I'm quite lost here and not sure what to do, my only option right now is to boot in recovery mode, but this isn't sustainable in a long term. Any help is appreciated. I only have Ubuntu installed, no dual boot problem with Windows.

Comment: You may need to install Nvidia drivers and in that case always keep Secure Boot OFF.  Also there are a few systems that don't work well with the 5.8 kernel branch. In that case uninstalling the HWE kernel and installing the generic (5.4) is also an option.

Comment: I've also tried the drivers, but I keep having the boot problem after a while. I am assuming it's related to the external monitor thing, since I've seen around here that it could be a problem, but I'm not sure. Went back to 5.4 kernel and it boots from grub now when I force shutdown, but I still can't reboot or properly boot when I switch it off through the menu.